# How to adjust xaml page for every resolution and screensize?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am developing a windows 8.1 store app.By default windows store apps generate pages which are having 10.6" screen size and 1366*768 resolution.I want my every xaml page to fit on all screen sizes and resolutions.I solved this problem by using a Viewbox but only one page is not behaving as expected.I am doing this:`<Viewbox>
        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>`

The grid is not taking the whole width of the page but Viewbox is taking.Please help.

Comment: Generally I'd say a viewbox wouldn't be required to accomplish your goal, but for giggles, do you have horizontalalignment/horizontalcontentalignment set to Stretch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the ViewBox will Stretch Uniform to maintain the aspect ratio of its contents. You can set its Stretch property to Fill if you want it to distort to fill the whole page.

You don't include the contents of the Grid in your code snippet, so it's not clear what all you have in there to know how it would stretch. Since it's stretching to fill vertically but not horizontally I expect your contents are taller than they are wide.

As Chris W notes in his comment, ViewBox is probably not what you want here. In general you're better off using flexible layout controls such as the Grid. If you remove the ViewBox the Grid (assuming it's in the root of the page) will expand to the full Window size. Using relative row and column sizes (as you do) rather than hardcoding sizes the layout should adjust to the page size.

For extreme differences such as portrait vs. landscape vs. skinny you may want to use Visual States to provide different layouts for the same content. MSDN's [Quickstart: Designing apps for different window sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn297195(v=win.10).aspx) goes into detail on how to do this.

Comment: By default the ViewBox will Stretch Uniform - Doesn't stretch on mine. I dragged to make the window bogger and every control stayed where is was leaving me with a big white band at the bottom of the screen. Why is something that should be really easy do difficult?